# Is there a way to get someones E-mail in Discord? Important

Tags: discord

So im going to be honest: i know nothing about coding, i just lost my discord account and i want to get my access to it back, but i forgot my E-mail. Can anybody help me get it back?
As i said, i know nothing about coding im just in need of help! And is something like that even possible?

The image i added is the one from the account btw.

It wont let me post it says, im not meeting their quality standards. I dont know what i need to do but i figured it out if you see this. Again im not sure if it the email thing even works

**if yes and if anybody is going to help me thank you so much**

Answer (score 0):

You will need to contact discord support where they may or may not be able to help you get the account back. It depends on the info you are able to provide them.

https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us

Comment: Sadly they said they cant tell me it because of privacy guidelines and stuff. Its okay if y'all cant help me.

Comment: If you've ever had your account info saved with Chrome, you can look through your password info to see the associated email. Go to chrome://settings , then Passwords (under autofill), and then search for discord.

Comment: Alternatively, you can search through all emails that you have access to for emails from discord, which may narrow it down.

Comment: Yea i tried to do that already sadly no result. Ive been trying for almost a year now